# php unset not working with array of objects

Tags: php

i have an array of objects received from mongodb i have a custom soft delete feature, for which i have to loop through the objects find the key `deleted_at` and unset it from the array this is how my array looks like if i dump it

```
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#41 (1) {
  [
    "storage": "ArrayObject":private
  ]=>
  array(15) {
    [
      0
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#26 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(4) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(18) "BCasdaadaadadasdas"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(20) "hank-zakroff@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(11) "11-22-33-44"
        [
          "deleted_at"
        ]=>
        string(19) "2019-08-21 10:08:43"
      }
    }
    [
      1
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#27 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(4) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(9) "ADasdBSDS"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(23) "haasdnk-zakroff@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(11) "03338142535"
        [
          "deleted_at"
        ]=>
        string(19) "2019-08-21 11:08:17"
      }
    }
    [
      2
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#28 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(12) "Hank Zakroff"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(20) "hank-zakroff@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(11) "03244424280"
      }
    }
    [
      3
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#29 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(12) "Hank Zakroff"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(20) "hank-zakroff@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(11) "03244424281"
      }
    }
    [
      4
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#30 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(9) "Kate Bell"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(17) "kate-bell@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(13) "(555)564-8583"
      }
    }
    [
      5
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#31 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(9) "Kate Bell"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(17) "kate-bell@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(13) "(415)555-3695"
      }
    }
    [
      6
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#32 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(14) "Daniel Higgins"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(17) "d-higgins@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(12) "555-478-7672"
      }
    }
    [
      7
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#33 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(14) "Daniel Higgins"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(17) "d-higgins@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(13) "(408)555-5270"
      }
    }
    [
      8
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#34 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(14) "Daniel Higgins"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(17) "d-higgins@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(13) "(408)555-3514"
      }
    }
    [
      9
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#35 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(14) "John Appleseed"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(22) "John-Appleseed@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(12) "888-555-5512"
      }
    }
    [
      10
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#36 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(14) "John Appleseed"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(22) "John-Appleseed@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(12) "888-555-1212"
      }
    }
    [
      11
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#37 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(9) "Anna Haro"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(17) "anna-haro@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(12) "555-522-8243"
      }
    }
    [
      12
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#38 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(12) "Hank Zakroff"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(20) "hank-zakroff@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(13) "(555)766-4823"
      }
    }
    [
      13
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#39 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(12) "Hank Zakroff"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(20) "hank-zakroff@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(13) "(707)555-1854"
      }
    }
    [
      14
    ]=>
    object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#40 (1) {
      [
        "storage": "ArrayObject":private
      ]=>
      array(3) {
        [
          "name"
        ]=>
        string(12) "David Taylor"
        [
          "email"
        ]=>
        string(20) "hank-zakroff@mac.com"
        [
          "mobileNo"
        ]=>
        string(12) "555-610-6679"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for unsetting the index i did what i normally do in arrays

```
foreach ($is_exist['contacts'] as $key => $value) {
    if(@$value['deleted_at']){
      unset($is_exist['contacts'][$key]);
    }
}
```

now i have matching objects at key 0 and 1 but the problem is it unsets the key 0 but not key 1 i have tried many combinations like

//pass by reference doesnot work at all

```
foreach ($is_exist['contacts'] as $key => &$value) {
    if(@$value['deleted_at']){
        unset($value);
    }
}
```

i even tried

```
reset($is_exist['contacts']);
```

just after my unset condition but that doesn't work as well

it's strange , this doesn't happen normally any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think you should try array_splice — Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else. In other words If you use \array_splice() then it will reindex keys of an array, but not for the associative keys. For associative keys use  \array_values() it can convert all keys to numerical keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... *the problem is it unsets the key 0 but not key 1*

It's generally not good practice to mutate an array in-place while iterating its items.

You're bound to run into this problem as the internal array pointer (PHP versions < 7) is destroyed in the `unset` operation.

You can make a copy of the original array and iterate over that copy while modifying the original array or better, make a filtered copy with undeleted documents.
I prefer the later approach to be straight-forward and clear on the intent. *e.g.*

```php
$contacts = $is_exist['contacts'];
$active_contacts = [];
foreach ($contacts as $key => &$value) {
    if(is_null(@$value['deleted_at']))
    {
      $active_contacts[] = @$value;
    }
}
$is_exist['contacts'] = $active_contacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Filter in the db query may be better than your php code.
2. If you want to filter it with your php code, use a new array to store the filter item instead of doing inplace modificaiton.

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $v){
    if(!$v['deleted_at']){
        $result[] = $v;
    }
}
```

or

```
$result = array_filter($array,function($v){
    return !$v['deleted_at'];
});
```